# JSON deserialization in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi How can i parse the following JSON

```
{"DataStats":[["Type","Name","valueDateTime","value","attr0","attr1","attr2"],
["AA","End Time","10/4/2014 12:00:00 AM","01:10:23.37","USA_325","expected","AA_overall"],
["AA","End Time","10/4/2014 12:00:00 AM","01:10:23.37","USA_325","expected","AA_overall"]]}
```

to Below model

```
    [ {Type : "AA",Name :"End Time",valueDateTime : "10/4/2014 12:00:00 AM", value : "01:10:23.37" ,
attr0 :"USA_325" , attr1 : "expected" , attr2 : "AA_overall"  },{Type : "AA",Name :"End Time",valueDateTime : "10/4/2014 12:00:00 AM", value : "01:10:23.37" ,
attr0 :"USA_325" , attr1 : "expected" , attr2 : "AA_overall"  }]
```

I have tried below

```
 $scope.ob = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($scope.j));

              for (var i=0; i <= $scope.ob.length; i++)
              {
                  console.log($scope.ob[i]);

              }
```

But i am not sure how to proceed further. Can any one help me ?

Thanks,

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...))` does essentially nothing. What is `$scope.j`? If it's a JSON string, then you just need `JSON.parse($scope.j)`.

Comment: Down voting with out comment is pet peeve of minew

Comment: @ChrisMartin ... it did nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two assumptions are made here:

1. That the first result of your JSON is the specification of the keys
2. That the results always follow the same order (e.g. index 0 is always the `Type` field).

With those two assumptions, it's easy to do this with a pair of nested for-loops.  Could get fancier with ES5 methods, but the index orders are important here (since your JSON depends on order of values) so I stuck with regular `for` loops.  Personally, I would reformat your JSON if possible to have it return in an easier format to deal with.

```
var json = '{"DataStats":[["Type","Name","valueDateTime","value","attr0","attr1","attr2"],["AA","End Time","10/4/2014 12:00:00 AM","01:10:23.37","USA_325","expected","AA_overall"],["AA","End Time","10/4/2014 12:00:00 AM","01:10:23.37","USA_325","expected","AA_overall"]]}';
var parsed = JSON.parse(json).DataStats;
var keys = parsed[0];

var result = [];
for (var i = 1; i < parsed.length; i++) {
  var aux = {};

  for (var j = 0; j < keys.length; j++) {
    aux[keys[j]] = parsed[i][j];
  }

  result.push(aux);
}

console.log(result);
```